# Add user to organization through Github API

Tags: javascript, github-api

I'm trying to add a member to an organization using Github API following the [docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/#add-or-update-organization-membership). I have this code for the request:

```
const url = `https://api.github.com/orgs/${org}/memberships/${user}`;
axios.put(url, {
        role: 'member',
}, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `token ${accessToken}`
    }
})
.then((response) => {
    console.log('response', response)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log('error', error)
});
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    documentation_url: "https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/#add-or-update-organization-membership",
    message: "You must be an admin to add or update an organization membership."
}
```

I have already checked that my user is owner of the organization.

I have created an OAuth App in the organization and as I understood I don't need to have restriction privileges.

Any idea how can I get what's going on here?

Comment: What privileges has the API token got?

Comment: Read & Write for Organization